# Tkinter how to get button image address

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I am writing a program for a school project and have come to a point where i need to check the image that is on my button so that i can run it through an if command as followed:

```
root=Tk()

flag = PhotoImage(file='flag.png')

box = PhotoImage(file='box.png')

def function(event):
    if(button.cget('image')==flag):
        button.config(image=box)
    else:
        button.config(image=flag)


button=Button(root)
button.config(image=box)
button.bind('<ButtonRelease>', function)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

i was expecting it to change the image between flag and box everytime i click on the button but instead it just changes the image to flag the first time i click and is unresponsive for the rest of the clicks

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do the test as `if(button.cget('image')==str(flag)):` (note addition of `str()` to the image).  The `image` option is just a string, containing the auto-generated name of the image object in the Tcl/Tk environment; the Python image object converts to this string, but doesn't contain the code needed to implement comparison to strings so you need to make this conversion explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
root=Tk()

flag = PhotoImage(file='Denaro.gif')

box = PhotoImage(file='Andre.gif')

def function(event):
    if(button.cget('image')=='pyimage1'):
        button.config(image=box)
    else:
        button.config(image=flag)


button=Button(root)
button.config(image=box)
button.bind('<ButtonRelease>', function)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe jasonharper's subsequent answer is a explanation and generalization of this one in that str(flag) will currently be 'pyimage1' (and str(box) will be 'pyimage2').