# How to check if a Button image is a certain image in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want when I click an image button it runs a function and check if the button image is, let's say, equal to `img1`:

`Button` code

```
b1 = Button(root, image=img1, bd=0, bg='#292424', activebackground='#292424', 
            command=lambda: press(b1))
```

Comment: Look at here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945329/tkinter-how-to-get-button-image-address>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not made a function with a variable. After the first click the variable equal 1 and the second click the variable equals 0?

**Edit:** I use this for my toggle button:

```
self.intervention_conciliation = tk.Button(frame_1, text="Non",
                                           command=self.clic_boutton_conciliation)
def clic_boutton_conciliation(self):
    # on va changer la couleur du bouton ainsi que l'inscription
    if self.intervention_conciliation["bg"] == "SystemButtonFace":
        self.intervention_conciliation["bg"] = "dim gray"
        self.intervention_conciliation["text"] = "Oui"
    else:
        self.intervention_conciliation["bg"] = "SystemButtonFace"
        self.intervention_conciliation["text"] = "Non"
```

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: I edit my previous post